# SQL объединить два запроса одной и той же таблицы в один

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть таблица
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

COUNT("Employee Name") GROUP BY "Manager Name", "Performance Score"
Мне посчитает кол-во оценок одного и того же типа у каждой менеджера, а COUNT("Employee Name") GROUP BY "Manager Name" должен считать Кол-во сотрудников у каждого менеджера

должно быть 4 столбца два из который вычисляемые
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как объединить эти два запроса, чтобы получить нужную таблицу?
Запрос 1:
'''SELECT "Manager Name", "Performance Score",  COUNT("Employee Name") as "Кол-во оценок"
FROM hr_dataset
GROUP BY "Manager Name", "Performance Score"
ORDER BY "Manager Name", "Кол-во оценок"'''
Запрос 2:
'''SELECT "Manager Name", COUNT("Employee Name") as "Кол-во сотрудников"
FROM hr_dataset
GROUP BY "Manager Name"
ORDER BY "Manager Name"'''

Comment: не понимаю, что движет людьми, когда они именуют поля заведомо зная что придется их экранировать каждый  раз в запросах. В любом случае, приведите пример исходных данных и желаемого результата.

Comment: Укажите точно СУБД, включая точную версию.

Answer (score 0):

Задачу решила таким методом:

```
SELECT 
  a."Manager Name", b."Performance Score", b."Кол-во оценок", 
  COUNT(b."Кол-во оценок") as "Кол-во сотрудников"
FROM hr_dataset a
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT "Manager Name", "Performance Score", COUNT("Employee Name") as "Кол-во оценок"
  FROM hr_dataset 
  GROUP BY "Manager Name", "Performance Score") b ON a."Manager Name" = b."Manager Name"
GROUP BY a."Manager Name", b."Performance Score", b."Кол-во оценок"
ORDER BY a."Manager Name", b."Кол-во оценок"
```